# CSS background-color:transparent after bg colour being set

Tags: css

With CSS, I'd like to set a background transparent after a colour already being set by its parent div.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="nobackground">This background is transparent</div>
    <div>This is not transparent</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    background-image:url("http://www.thomaslovgren.com/wp-content/uploads/spaceship1.png");
}
#content{
    background-color:#F00;
}
#nobackground{
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7HfJa/1/

A possible solution:

```
#content{
}
#content div:not(#nobackground){
    background-color:#F00;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7HfJa/4/

But, is there any **better good-looking solution** like a single statement to the div like `background-color:transparent`?

Comment: i think maybe you want `div#nobackground { background-color: transparent; } div { background-color: #ff0000; }`, and nothing for the `#content` ( based on the fiddle )

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it won't happen. You're making a child div transparent, and even with no background, it will show what's directly behind it, which is its parent div. If the parent div is red, the child will show the red background. You basically want to delete the background out of the parent for that single location where the child is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could do: http://jsfiddle.net/8c54H/

```
div#nobackground ~ div {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

although that assumes the red divs follow the transparent div

Comment: Not really what I was looking for but the closest one. I assume that what I was looking for is impossible after reading some of your comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make your selector more specific:

```
#content #nobackground {
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: You can't make a transparent "hole" in a parent item that has a defined background by putting something on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do what you want properly with the HTML that you have. You can't have something within a content box show the background from something behind that box without redeclaring the same background.

Better would be to just move the HTML around so that the "transparent" element is simply in a container with no background.

If you want to fake it with the HTML you have, you could try something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/PxKy8/2/

It just puts a border around the content and a background on the elements that actually need it.

```
#content{
    border:5px solid #F00;
}
#nobackground {
}
.redbg {
   background-color:#F00;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="nobackground">This background is transparent</div>
    <div class="redbg">This is not transparent</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: What are you trying to accomplish? If you want it to look like your last example, why not this:

http://jsfiddle.net/f4qZP/

Comment: With all my respects, I think that's uglier than my solution.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are trying to do... If you just want one div to have background and the other not, why not just declare background on the one div and nothing on the other? Wasn't trying to make something look good, just something that behaved the way you want :P